# How to properly mount a partition from one ubuntu machine (client) to another (server)?

Tags: networking, server, partitioning, mount, samba

Basic setup is as follows.  A desktop and a laptop.  Both have ubuntu installed.  The desktop is going to function as a server.  The laptop is going to function as a workstation.

Basically, there is a mounted partition on the desktop.  It is mounted and functioning properly on the server.  From here, I would like to know how to properly share and mount the partition on the client.  I've installed smbfs on the server following several sets of instructions on the web.  The obstacle is mounting the share on the laptop workstation.

I've read several guides and am getting conflicting advice about which protocol to use (CIFS or SMB).  My setup is ubuntu server 14.04 on the server end.  Ubuntu mate 15 on the client.

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use ```sshfs```? From my experience that's the fastest way of sharing drives, it offers you the capability to add an entry to ```fstab``` and doesn't require to configure anything but ssh.  Furthermore many recent file managers (Nautilus eg) have build-in drive-mounting capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to be mounting the drive from another Linux machine and don't require Windows support I would discourage you from using smbfs (aka samba, aka CIFS).  I've never setup a samba share on Linux without ripping at least half of my hair out.

I would recommend just using NFS- it's simpler, easier to setup, and faster:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Both Samba and Windows sharing use the SMB protocol.  This has also been called CIFS.

If you want to mount a file system (partition) on your client from the server you will need to install Samba on the server and then configure the services.  Then you will need to *share* the partition on the server before you can mount it on the client.

The term **smbfs** refers to a installable package (deprecated), not the protocol or the server.  The current package for the server is *samba*.  The Samba client routines should be installed by default.  If not I believe the current packages are **cifs-common** and **cifs-utils**